# "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed." yeah baby!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions

Since everything is pretty much subjective here, perhaps this message should be disabled on this site.

"The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."

Thoughts?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Should we have a "not subjective enough" close reason?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/14/should-we-have-a-not-subjective-enough-close-reason)

Comment: @Chinmay: I don't see how they're the same. This is about the "subjective" warning when writing a question title.

Comment: They are the same, more or less, since if one changes, the other should change too.

Comment: Funny, my computer always says my questions are likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I concur.  I don't know what level of customization we can do, but I understand we have CSS control, so we could at least hide that message, if not replace is as per Dori's suggestion.

Comment: Admins could probably change or remove the message. CSS hiding will only work until somebody pulls up the close box in Firebug